# Parsing Configuration File To Excel-Like View

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, fileparsing

I have a firewall configuration file that goes like this:

```
{
    "javaClass": "some text",
    "rules": {
        "javaClass": "java.util.LinkedList",
        "list": [
            {
                "block": true,
                "conditions": {
                    "javaClass": "java.util.LinkedList",
                    "list": [
                        {
                            "conditionType": "DST_PORT",
                            "invert": false,
                            "javaClass": "some text",
                            "value": "21"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "Block and flag all traffic destined to port 21",
                "enabled": false,
                "flag": true,
                "javaClass": "some text",
                "ruleId": 100018
            },
            {
                "block": true,
                "conditions": {
                    "javaClass": "java.util.LinkedList",
                    "list": [
                        {
                            "conditionType": "SRC_ADDR",
                            "invert": false,
                            "javaClass": "some text",
                            "value": "1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "Block and flag all TCP traffic from 1.2.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0",
                "enabled": false,
                "flag": true,
                "javaClass": "some text",
                "ruleId": 100019
            },
            {
                "block": true,
                "conditions": {
                    "javaClass": "java.util.LinkedList",
                    "list": [
                        {
                            "conditionType": "DST_ADDR",
                            "invert": false,
                            "javaClass": "some text",
                            "value": "1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "conditionType": "DST_PORT",
                            "invert": false,
                            "javaClass": "some text",
                            "value": "1000-5000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "Accept and flag all traffic to the range 1.2.3.1 - 1.2.3.10 to ports 1000-5000",
                "enabled": false,
                "flag": true,
                "javaClass": "some text",
                "ruleId": 100020
            }
        ]
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

I'm trying to extract the `list` part, then, extract parts of it for storing the data.

Now, I'm able to load the whole file using `myConfigDetails.Text = File.ReadAllLines("firewall.settings_9.js");`, but I'm unable to extract the data I want .. The rule can have no conditions, single conditions or multiple conditions ...

I created the class below to store the data in temporarily for further usage:

```
public class fwDATA
{
    public string ruleID;
    public bool ruleBlock;
    public string ruleValue;
    public string ruleDesc;
    public bool ruleEnabled;
    public bool ruleFlag;
}
```

Can someone guide me to the correct way to extract the list parts (both the rule and conditions)

Parts I need:

- "block"
- "conditionType"
- "value"
- "description"
- "enabled"
- "flag"
- "ruleId"

Comment: Look around for a Json deserializer. It will do the job.

Comment: @dymanoid .. I've been looking, but couldn't find a clear way to achieve this. Do you have any tutorial or code snippet that is working? I will work on amending it to suite my needs